# How to uninstall Ubuntu Software Center in 11.10?

Tags: command-line, 11.10, software-center, sudo, uninstall

I am trying to uninstall software center for ubuntu oneric using the command `sudo apt-get remove software center` and get this as result

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package software
E: Unable to locate package center
```

I did it once and got it fixed but now it does't work. I have an issue with the software center it keeps on repeatedly giving message saying send error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are missing the hiphen between *software* and *center*. The command you seem to be looking for is `sudo apt-get remove software-center`

Comment: summary for the errors i get 
1)update-software-center crashed with SIGSEGV in malloc()
2)update-apt-xapian-index crashed with error in loop(): [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
3)piston_get_reviews_helper.py crashed with AttributeError in __main__: 'exceptions.ValueError' object has no attribute 'doc'error id's OOPS-2099DU5, OOPS-2099M2, OOPS-2099AT7

Comment: hey i'm still having issues with the software center because i removed it and tried to install from the synaptic package manager and i get a message 
failed to retrieve packages ignore or close